# Selecting database row android app SQLite

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have created a database in an android app. Here is how I create it.

DatabaseHelper.java:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

static final String dbName="db_dr.droid";

static final String MedhistTable="tbl_medhist";
static final String colName="MedHistName";
static final String colAge="MedHistAge";
static final String colWeight="MedHistWeight";
static final String colHeight="MedHistHeight";
static final String colMedHist="MedHistHist";

static final String DTipsTable="tbl_dailytips";
static final String colID="DTipsId";
static final String colText="DTipsText";

static final String viewHist="ViewHist";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
      super(context, dbName, null,33); 
      }

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+MedhistTable+" ("+colName+ " TEXT , "+
            colAge + " INTEGER, " +
            colWeight + " INTEGER, " +
            colHeight + " INTEGER, " +
            colMedHist + " TEXT) ");

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+DTipsTable+" ("+colID+ " INTEGER , "+
            colText + " TEXT)");


     db=this.getWritableDatabase();
     ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
       cv.put(colID, 1);
       cv.put(colText, "It's easy to fit physical activities into your daily routine. Walk, bike or jog to see friends. Take a 10-minute activity break every hour while you read, do homework or watch TV. Climb stairs instead of taking an escalator or elevator. Try to do these things for a total of 30 minutes every day.");
       db.insert(DTipsTable, colID, cv);

       cv.put(colID, 2);
       cv.put(colText, "Breakfast fills your 'empty tank' to get you going after a long night without food. And it can help you do better in school. Easy to prepare breakfasts include cold cereal with fruit and low-fat milk, whole-wheat toast with peanut butter, yogurt with fruit, whole-grain waffles or even last night's pizza!");
       db.insert(DTipsTable, colID, cv);

       cv.put(colID, 3);
       cv.put(colText, "Snacks are a great way to refuel. Choose snacks from different food groups - a glass of low-fat milk and a few graham crackers, an apple or celery sticks with peanut butter and raisins, or some dry cereal. If you eat smart at other meals, cookies, chips and candy are OK for occasional snacking.");
       db.insert(DTipsTable, colID, cv);

       cv.put(colID, 4);
       cv.put(colText, "Vigorous work-outs - when you're breathing hard and sweating - help your heart pump better, give you more energy and help you look and feel best. Start with a warm-up that stretches your muscles. Include 20 minutes of aerobic activity, such as running, jogging, or dancing. Follow-up with activities that help make you stronger such as push-ups or lifting weights. Then cool-down with more stretching and deep breathing.");
       db.insert(DTipsTable, colID, cv);

       cv.put(colID, 5);
       cv.put(colText, "Vigorous work-outs - when you're breathing hard and sweating - help your heart pump better, give you more energy and help you look and feel best. Start with a warm-up that stretches your muscles. Include 20 minutes of aerobic activity, such as running, jogging, or dancing. Follow-up with activities that help make you stronger such as push-ups or lifting weights. Then cool-down with more stretching and deep breathing.");
       db.insert(DTipsTable, colID, cv);

       cv.put(colID, 6);
       cv.put(colText, "Being active is much more fun with friends or family. Encourage others to join you and plan one special physical activity event, like a bike ride or hiking, with a group each week.");
       db.insert(DTipsTable, colID, cv);

       cv.put(colID, 7);
       cv.put(colText, "Eat more grains, fruits and vegetables. These foods give you carbohydrates for energy, plus vitamins, minerals and fiber. Besides, they taste good! Try breads such as whole-wheat, bagels and pita. Spaghetti and oatmeal are also in the grain group." +
               "Bananas, strawberries and melons are some great tasting fruits. Try vegetables raw, on a sandwich or salad.");
       db.insert(DTipsTable, colID, cv);

       cv.put(colID, 8);
       cv.put(colText, "Whether you take a physical education class or do other physical activities at school, such as intramural sports, structures activities are a sure way to feel good, look good and stay physically fit.");
       db.insert(DTipsTable, colID, cv);

       cv.put(colID, 9);
       cv.put(colText, "A healthy eating style is like a puzzle with many parts. Each part -- or food -- is different. Some foods may have more fat, sugar or salt while others may have more vitamins or fiber. There is a place for all these foods. What makes a diet good or bad is how foods fit together. Balancing your choices is important. Fit in a higher-fat food, like pepperoni pizza, at dinner by choosing lower-fat foods at other meals. And don't forget about moderation. If two pieces of pizza fill you up, you don't need a third.");
       db.insert(DTipsTable, colID, cv);

       cv.put(colID, 10);
       cv.put(colText, "Take advantage of physical activities you and your friends enjoy doing together and eat the foods you like. Be adventurous - try new sports, games and other activities as well as new foods. You'll grow stronger, play longer, and look and feel better! Set realistic goals - don't try changing too much at once.");
       db.insert(DTipsTable, colID, cv);

       db.close();

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldversion, int newversion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ MedhistTable);

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ DTipsTable);

    db.close();
}

String getTips()
  {

   SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();

  // Cursor cur=db.rawQuery("SELECT "+ colID +" as _id," + colText + "from "+ DTipsTable + "WHERE ",new String [] {});

   Cursor c=db.query(DTipsTable, new String[]{colID+" as _id",colText},
           colID+"=?", new String[]{colText}, null, null, null);

   c.moveToFirst();
   db.close();
   c.close();
   return c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("colText"));  

  }

}
```

And at my home.java I called the database helper to retrieve a specific row.

```
public class Home extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
DatabaseHelper dbhelp = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);


      String tips = dbhelp.getTips();


    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setTitle("Daily Health Tips")
    .setMessage(tips)
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setNegativeButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
               }
           });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

    alert.show();


}
```

But the app is being stopped. Here is the Catlog

```
    08-21 16:04:48.588: E/Trace(630): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
08-21 16:04:48.958: D/dalvikvm(630): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 258K, 4% free 8142K/8455K, paused 69ms, total 73ms
08-21 16:04:49.078: D/dalvikvm(630): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 194K, 5% free 8257K/8647K, paused 44ms, total 54ms
08-21 16:04:49.218: D/AndroidRuntime(630): Shutting down VM
08-21 16:04:49.218: W/dalvikvm(630): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
08-21 16:04:49.228: E/AndroidRuntime(630): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-21 16:04:49.228: E/AndroidRuntime(630): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{dr.droid/dr.droid.Home}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getDatabase called recursively
08-21 16:04:49.228: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
08-21 16:04:49.228: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
08-21 16:04:49.228: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
08-21 16:04:49.228: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
08-21 16:04:49.228: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-21 16:04:49.228: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-21 16:04:49.228: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
08-21 16:04:49.228: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-21 16:04:49.228: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-21 16:04:49.228: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
08-21 16:04:49.228: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-21 16:04:49.228: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-21 16:04:49.228: E/AndroidRuntime(630): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getDatabase called recursively
08-21 16:04:49.228: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:204)
08-21 16:04:49.228: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
08-21 16:04:49.228: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at dr.droid.DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DatabaseHelper.java:44)
08-21 16:04:49.228: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
08-21 16:04:49.228: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
08-21 16:04:49.228: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at dr.droid.DatabaseHelper.getTips(DatabaseHelper.java:104)
08-21 16:04:49.228: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at dr.droid.Home.onCreate(Home.java:20)
08-21 16:04:49.228: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
08-21 16:04:49.228: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
08-21 16:04:49.228: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
08-21 16:04:49.228: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  ... 11 more
08-21 16:04:52.138: I/Process(630): Sending signal. PID: 630 SIG: 9
```

Any help/suggestions will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Remove `public Home h = new Home();` from helper class... You should never call Activity class constructor...

Comment: Already change it too. Still same prob but new error. See my update catlog. THanks!

Comment: Second... Remove `db = this.getWriteableDatabase();` from onCreate of helper class... And do not close db in it...

Comment: @ljpv14 change sequence in getTips function String tip=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("colText"));  
   c.close();
   return tip;

Answer (score 0):

you have to initialize dbhelp variable in or after on create function

Comment: still the apps stops, but I got a new error at my sql statements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class Home extends Activity {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    DatabaseHelper dbhelp = new DatabaseHelper(this);
     String tips = dbhelp.getTips();


    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setTitle("Daily Health Tips")
    .setMessage(tips)
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setNegativeButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
               }
           });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

    alert.show();


}
```

You should try to move the getTips() methods in Home class. That way your code will look more cleaner.

Comment: Thanks! Already did that. But it seems to be there's an error at my database creation. Can you help me to debug it? Thanks! See my post for the updated Catlog and databasehelper

Answer (score 0):

Your sql contains errors:

```
  db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+MedhistTable+" ("+colName+ " TEXT , "+
            colAge + " INTEGER +)" +
            colWeight + " INTEGER " +
            colHeight + " INTEGER " +
            colMedHist + " TEXT ");

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+DTipsTable+" ("+colID+ " INTEGER , "+
            colText + " TEXT +)");
```

should be

```
  db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+MedhistTable+" ("+colName+ " TEXT , "+
            colAge + " INTEGER, " +
            colWeight + " INTEGER, " +
            colHeight + " INTEGER, " +
            colMedHist + " TEXT) ");

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+DTipsTable+" ("+colID+ " INTEGER , "+
            colText + " TEXT)");
```

Comment: Thank you for noticing. Still got the same prob. The catlog gives me this. 08-21 15:44:42.717: E/AndroidRuntime(685): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{dr.droid/dr.droid.Home}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getDatabase called recursively
Any ideas?

Comment: Guessing, because you left out the most important piece of text: the class and line number where this error is showing.
Probably:
- remove SQLiteDatabase db2=this.getWritableDatabase();
- used db. instead of db2.

Comment: I noticed that to. Change it and the catLog gives me a different error now. See my post for the updated catlog.

Comment: Do a little debugging, and see what is going wrong. You have a loop.. remove public Home h = new Home();
Also remove db=this.getWritableDatabase();

Comment: Thank you for the advise. I finally end up debugging errors on how I select rows at my database.